# python regex search until parenthesis match

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract some data from a string like this (VHDL code):

```
entBody = """entity pci_bfm is                                                            
  generic(                                                                   
    G_INST_NAME            : string          := "PCI_BFM";                   
    G_HANDLE_NO            : rpciBfmHandleNo := 0;                           
    G_IDSEL_POS_EXT_TARGET : idsel_pos       := 30;                          
    G_IDSEL_POS_INT_TARGET : idsel_pos       := 29                           
    );                                                                       
  port(                                                                      
    i_tb_stop  : in    boolean;                       -- Testbench global sto
    o_clk      : out   std_logic;                     -- PCI clock.          
    o_rstn     : out   std_logic;                     -- PCI reset.          
    o_idsel    : out   std_logic;                     -- Initialization devic
    i_reqn     : in    std_logic;                     -- Request. The reqn in
    o_gntn     : out   std_logic;                     -- Grant. The gntn onpu
    io_ad      : inout std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- Address/data bus. Th
    io_cben    : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- Command/byte enable.
    io_par     : inout std_logic;                     -- Parity. The par sign
    io_framen  : inout std_logic;                     -- Frame. The framen si
    io_irdyn   : inout std_logic;                     -- Initiator ready. The
    io_devseln : inout std_logic;                     -- Device select. Targe
    io_trdyn   : inout std_logic;                     -- Target ready. The tr
    io_stopn   : inout std_logic;                     -- Stop. The stopn sign
    io_perrn   : inout std_logic;                     -- Parity error. The pe
    i_serrn    : in    std_logic;                     -- System error. The se
    i_intan    : in    std_logic;                     -- Interrupt A. The int
    o_lockn    : out   std_logic                      -- Locked operations. R
    );                                                                       
end entity pci_bfm;"""
```

The VHDL comments do not have all the same size, I truncated them to be easier to read.

I am interested to get everything between 'port(' and last ');' (the one that closes port declarations). Of course the VHDL declarations may not be well indented and formatted as here.

I have a Python 2.7.x regex for this:

```
pattern = re.compile("port\s*\((.*?)\s+\)\s*;")
match3 = pattern.search(entBody)
ports = match3.group(1)
```

It works well if the closing ); is not immediately after the last declaration. The following will not work:

```
entBody2 = """entity QSPI_FLASH_SPANSION_S25FL_BFM is
  generic
    (
      G_INST_NAME : string  := "QSPI_FLASH_SPANSION_S25FL_BFM";
      G_HANDLE_NO : integer := 2
      );
  port (
    tb_stop : in    boolean;                       -- Testbench global stop.
    sclk    : in    std_logic;
    csn     : in    std_logic;
    sdat    : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end;"""
```

If I change my regex a little bit like this:

```
pattern = re.compile("port\s*\((.*?)\s*\)\s*;") # \s* instead of \s+
```

then the search will end at 'io_ad      : inout std_logic_vector(31 downto 0' which is not good at all.

I was wondering if I can use regex to to a search like this, i.e. to count opening parenthesis and only stop when all parenthesis are closed.

If there is no simple way, I will do a simple string search using string functions to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: *I truncated them to be easier to read* - are you sure you preserved the same format? How can you define the leading/trailing boundaries and the content inside?

Answer (score 1):

Here you want to match the characters including newline. So use pattern `\s\S` with in a character class.

`\s` match the any whitespace character.

`\S` match the any non whitespace character

```
match3 =re.search(r"port\(([\s\S]+?)\);\s+\n",entBody)
```

Or [S](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) flag. Helps to match any character including newlines.

```
match3 =re.search(r"port\((.+?)\);\s+\n",entBody,re.S)
```

Comment: A word of warning: This will capture all text between `port(` and _the last closing parens `)` in the entire text_. While it may work in this specific case, I doubt this is a good solution for real world scenarios. All you need to do to break this solution is to move the `generic` section after the `port` section.

Comment: @Rawing Thank you for your comment post edited

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex:

```
/port\s*\((.+)\)\s*;/s
```

Breaking it down:

```
port            # matches the characters port literally (case sensitive)
\s*             # match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ] Between zero and unlimited times
\(              # matches the character ( literally
(.+)            # capturing group start - matching any character - Between one and unlimited times
\)              # matches the character ) literally
\s*             # match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ] Between zero and unlimited times
;               # matches the character ; literally

s               # modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
```

[**REGEX DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/rQ6rM1/4)

[**IDEONE DEMO**](http://ideone.com/KOm0I0)

---

**UPDATE:** If there is a case when there is something else after the `port(...)` you can check following regex:

[`/port\s*\((.*?)(?:\)\s*;\s*\w)/s`](https://regex101.com/r/rQ6rM1/6)

Comment: This only works if `port` is the last section in the code. If, for example, the `generic` section was below the `port` section, this wouldn't work. Also, you might want to allow whitespace between the closing parens and the semicolon.

Comment: @Rawing Thank you. I will work on the modifications you mentioned.